# How do I robustly typeset a double-hat?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, accents

I'm trying to typeset a symbol with two hat accents (useful for denoting superoperators in quantum mechanics, for instance), but `\hat{\hat{L}}` produces too much space between the hats. I found one approach [on a LaTeX forum](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=11426) that seems to work, but it requires manual adjustment for each letter that I might want to typeset. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I thinks it's acceptable to use `amsmath` and `\hat{\hat{L}}` directly. It is also used in manual of `amsmath`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, I wrote that suggestion at LaTeX Community, but there I assumed the person wanted fine-grained control. If you don't, then maybe something like this would be more suitable? You may need to tweak the -0.35ex to your liking, though not separately for each character.

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\newlength{\dhatheight}
\newcommand{\doublehat}[1]{%
    \settoheight{\dhatheight}{\ensuremath{\hat{#1}}}%
    \addtolength{\dhatheight}{-0.35ex}%
    \hat{\vphantom{\rule{1pt}{\dhatheight}}%
    \smash{\hat{#1}}}}
\begin{document}

$\doublehat{x} \doublehat{L} \doublehat{\prod}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you! One last question, though: would using \mathchoice be a reasonable way of making your code work in a super/subscript context? Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm. I hadn't thought of sub/superscripts. Yeah, \mathchoice could probably work. Do you need help or do you think you can work it out on your own?

Comment: I got it. It's not all that elegant, as I'm not used to the intricacies of LaTeX macro writing yet, but it does typeset superscript double-hats quite nicely. http://pastebin.com/XctVhueR

Comment: The `accents` package is needed since plain TeX yields good horizontal alignment of the accent only for single characters; `amsmath` has some handling of double accents, but only the `accents` package is able to handle the correct positioning of the `\hat` over your more complicated construction.

Comment: I needed a `\triplehat`, so I copied this definition for `\doublehat`, then renamed it to `\triplehat`, and finally replaced the two nested references to `\hat` with `\doublehat`. It worked beautifully!

Answer (score 6):

An alternative macro that doesn't depend on package `accents`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hathat}[1]{% 
\begingroup%
  \let\macc@kerna\z@%
  \let\macc@kernb\z@%
  \let\macc@nucleus\@empty%
  \hat{\raisebox{.2ex}{\vphantom{\ensuremath{#1}}}\smash{\hat{#1}}}%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

It is inspired by [frabjous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/411/frabjous)'s answer and [David's answer under another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/564502/63179).

---

An updated solution that supports subscript math style.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\hathat}[1]{% 
\begingroup%
  \let\macc@kerna\z@%
  \let\macc@kernb\z@%
  \let\macc@nucleus\@empty%
  \hat{\mathchoice%
    {\raisebox{.2ex}{\vphantom{\ensuremath{\displaystyle #1}}}}%
    {\raisebox{.2ex}{\vphantom{\ensuremath{\textstyle #1}}}}%
    {\raisebox{.16ex}{\vphantom{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle #1}}}}%
    {\raisebox{.14ex}{\vphantom{\ensuremath{\scriptscriptstyle #1}}}}%
    \smash{\hat{#1}}}%
\endgroup%
}
\makeatother
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Works nicely, but .2ex is probably not enough; I'd suggest .35ex, as in frabjous's answer above.

Comment: How can we make it work as a subscript, e.g., in $\sum_{\hathat{y}}$? Currently when I'm putting it in a subscript, the hats get separated a lot.

Comment: @pms I updated the solution.  Now it works for all math styles.