# Cannot add hat over smashed hat

Tags: accents

Why does the following simple code raise `Undefined control sequence` error?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\hat{\smash{\hat f}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?  Having a double hat?  What is important about the need for `\smash`? Adding an accent to a smashed quantity, in general, makes no sense, as it would not know where to put it.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Right, I want to have double hat.  What I actually have is `$\hat{\raisebox{.2ex}{\vphantom{f}}\smash{\hat{f}}}$`.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10508/

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you.  I knew that solution. But it uses the package `accents` which is not compatible with a conference template.  So I'm trying to understand how their solution works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Steven says using `\smash` here probably doesn't work well in any case, but it should not give an internal command undefined error.

I haven't fully traced it but at one point the internal accent nesting counter gets set to 5 presumably because it is confused by teh `\mathchoice` in `\smash` evaluating its argument 4 times (in each of the styles display, text, script and scriptscript)

The simplest, although not necessarily best fix is to give the internal lengths a default setting of 0pt so if you end up here they just add a zero kern rather than error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\let\macc@kerna\z@
\let\macc@kernb\z@
\let\macc@nucleus\@empty
\makeatother
\begin{document}

$\hat{\smash{\hat f}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works surprisingly well.  I got command undefined error when writing my double-hat macro `\newcommand{\hathat}[1]{\hat{\raisebox{.2ex}{\vphantom{\ensuremath{#1}}}\smash{\hat{#1}}}}`.  Your "simplest" fix makes it work!

Comment: It seems that `\macc@nucleus` should be reset every time.  Otherwise, try compile `$\hat{\hat x}$  $\hat{\smash{\hat{f}}}$`, [the outcome is hilarious](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=zzvp69).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to place a hat on a smashed quantity makes no sense, as the height of the smashed quantity is set to 0pt.  In the 3rd line, I emulate such an attempt.  Yuck.  First 2 lines are recommended...either remove the `\smash`, or only `\smash` at the end of the process.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
$\hat{\hat f}$ no smash

$\smash{\hat{\hat f}}$ final result smashed

$\sbox0{$\smash{\hat f}$}\hat{\box0}$ hatting a smash makes no sense
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank Steven and David for your answers.

The simplest fix I found so far is `\usepackage{accents}`.  (Though unfortunately for me, `accents` is not compatible with a conference template I'm using.)